# Callifornia LLC: how to pick calendar vs fiscal year for filing Form 568?

Tags: united-states, taxes, limited-liability-company, california

As title says, how do I pick calendar vs fiscal year for filing Form 568? I called the FTB, who told me to call the Secretary of State, who then told me to call the FTB.. Now I'm here.

I Googled as well, and it sounds like I can just pick one that is convenient for my LLC?